# Why are invited readers not able to access my private Blogger site?

Tags: blogger

I have a private blog on blogger.com. I have invited about 18 people to read it and 11 of them have successfully accepted the invitation and can now read my posts. But the other 7 people don't seem to have received their invites. One would-be reader sent me this yesterday after I told her to try and log-in:
"I tried to read this but it's saying I don't have access. I want access!"
I have invited her with the same (yahoo) email address she is writing to me from. Another friend also hasn't received the invite and has tried twice. 
Also I have NO IDEA what the invite email says, and there seems no way for me to find out or send a copy to myself.

This seems really odd - it's the first impression of my blog. Is there no way I can see what Blogger is saying?
Main issue thought is getting people access. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I have just deleted the invites and re-invited everyone individually as per a tip on another forum but I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only happening to some of the people, that would seem to point to a problem other than Blogger not sending the emails out.
Have the individuals who didn't get the email check their spam/junk folders in case it landed there by mistake.
You could also have them add your email address (if Blogger uses it as the "from" address) to their address books so future emails won't get filtered.

If you have a second/alternate email address, have Blogger send an invite to that email so you can see what the invite looks like.
If you don't have one, set up a free temporary email account with **<strike>[Forward Cat](https://forward.cat/)</strike>** and send the invite there; it will be forwarded to your real email address.